# Humans Voice Frequency?

Tags: acoustics, frequency, biophysics

Do all human beings have a different voice frequency like they have different finger prints? as all of us are unique so probably our vocal folds make different vibrations while saying a same word that may cause in different frequencies.

Comment: And the *physics* question here is?

Comment: People have a voice _print_ which is a combination of the spectral content of their voice, together with how they pronounce different vowels, speed, etc. It is used for voice authentication - usually one step in complex multi-factor authentication. But that's not really a physics question. See for example [this link](http://expertpages.com/news/voiceprint_identification.htm)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about physiology of speech, not physics.

Comment: You could find out about this from an internet search.

Comment: It might be argued that the question could be answered in terms of resonant frequencies of the larynx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [library of expert witnesses](http://expertpages.com/news/voiceprint_identification.htm):

> The fundamental theory for voice identification rests on the premise that every voice is individually characteristic enough to distinguish it from others through voiceprint analysis. There are two general factors involved in the process of human speech. The first factor in determining voice uniqueness lies in the sizes of the vocal cavities, such as the throat, nasal and oral cavities, and the shape, length and tension of the individual's vocal cords located in the larynx. The vocal cavities are resonators, much like organ pipes, which reinforce some of the overtones produced by the vocal cords, which produce formats or voiceprint bars. The likelihood that two people would have all their vocal cavities the same size and configuration and coupled identically appears very remote.
>
> The second factor in determining voice uniqueness lies in the manner in which the articulators or muscles of speech are manipulated during speech. The articulators include the lips, teeth, tongue, soft palate and jaw muscles whose controlled interplay produces intelligible speech. Intelligible speech is developed by the random learning process of imitating others who are communicating. The likelihood that two people could develop identical use patterns of their articulators also appears very remote.
>
> Therefore, **the chance that two speakers would have identical vocal cavity dimensions and configurations coupled with identical articulator use patterns appears extremely remote**. While there have been claims that several voices have been found to be indistinguishable, no evidence to support such allegations has been published, offered for examination or demonstrated to the authors.

Comment: so all these factors make the frequency of the voices of different persons different from each other ?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: are you sure ? lol